# How to turn vector into cross matrix with diagonal filling?

Tags: arrays, r

How can you turn a vector into a matrix (2d array) with only the first diagonale filled?

```
x <- 1:3
y <- array(dim=c(3,3))
y[x,x] <- x
> y
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
```

so that y instead becomes:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   NA   NA
[2,]   NA    2   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    3
```

This smells like there is a trivial solution, but I can't see it yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
 (NA^!diag(x))*diag(x)
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]    1   NA   NA
 #[2,]   NA    2   NA
 #[3,]   NA   NA    3
```

Or with less code-golfing

```
 x1 <- diag(x)
 x1[lower.tri(x1, diag=FALSE)|upper.tri(x1, diag=FALSE)] <- NA
```

Or another option suggested by @David Arenburg would be to create a NA matrix and then fill the diagonal with 'x'

```
 res <- matrix(NA, length(x), length(x)) 
 diag(res) <- x
```

Comment: Hi, this is great, I can even live with "0" fillings, so just missed the diag(x) command. Thanks!

Comment: Or a bit less code golfing will be `res <- matrix(NA, length(x), length(x)) ; diag(res) <- x`

Comment: @szeta If you can live with zeros instead of NAs you could create a sparse matrix,